# ManyToMany relation with extra column and no composite key concept using Spring and Hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate

I have two table : Trade and Location and there exist many-to-many relationship.Now i have to add extra column in intermediate table trade_location as "status".I have searched a lot but all the solution provided is with composite key.But i want a solution without composite key as "trade_location" table as its own unique primary key as "id".Any suggestion to achieve manytomany relationship with extra column and without composite key.
Thanks.Here are my pojo :

```
    enter code here
          @Entity
          @Table(name="trade")
         public class Trade {
     @Id
     @GeneratedValue
     private Long id;
         @Column(unique=true)
     private String name;

     @OneToOne
     @JoinColumn(name="sectorId")
     private Sector sector;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "trades",fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Location> location =new HashSet<Location>();
    public Long getId() {
     return id;
    }

   @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "trades")
   private Set<Trainee> trainee = new HashSet<Trainee>();
       //getter and setter here
    }

    @Entity
    @Table(name="location")
    public class Location implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;


    private String name;
    private Long stateId;
    private Long districtId;
    private Long cityId;
    private Long zoneId;
    @Column(name="yearEstablishment")
    private String yearOfEstablishment;

    @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "trade_location",
            joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="locationId")},
            inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="tradeId")})
    private Set<Trade> trades = new HashSet<Trade>();
        //getter and setter
 }
```

//Edited one

```
@Entity
@Table(name="trade")
public class Trade {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;
@Column(unique=true)
private String name;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name="sectorId")
private Sector sector;

/*@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "trades",fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<Location> location =new HashSet<Location>();*/

@OneToMany(mappedBy="trade")
private Set<TradeLocation> tradeLocation = new HashSet<TradeLocation>(0);

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "trades")
private Set<Trainee> trainee = new HashSet<Trainee>();

@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name="tradeId")
private Set<Batch>batches =new HashSet<Batch>();
//getter and setter
```

}

```
@Entity
```

@Table(name="location")
   public class Location {

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;


private String name;
private Long stateId;
private Long districtId;
private Long cityId;
private Long zoneId;
@Column(name="yearEstablishment")
private String yearOfEstablishment;

/*@ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "trade_location",
            joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="locationId")},
            inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="tradeId")})
private Set<Trade> trades = new HashSet<Trade>();*/

@OneToMany(mappedBy="location")
private Set<TradeLocation>tradeLocation=new HashSet<TradeLocation>(0);

/*getter and setter*/
```

}

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "trade_location")
public class TradeLocation implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="tradeId")
private Trade trade;

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="locationId")
private Location location;

//getter and setter
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create an Entity named `TradeLocation` if you want it to act as an independent table with an id.

And change your Relationships to following.

`Trade` <-> 1..* `TradeLocation` *..1 <-> `Location`

Comment: I did the same but it's not working as Trade also have one-to-one relation with Batch class.It's giving following error :  Error performing load command : org.hibernate.HibernateException: More than one row with the given identifier was found: 5